# How to check if the beginning elements of array in matlab is the same

Tags: matlab

I would like to see if an array starts with the same elements as another array without having to write a bunch of for loops going through each element individually.

For example if I had the arrays below

```
Array1 = [1 2 3 4]
Array2 = [1 2 3 4 5 3 2 5 7]

Array3 = [1 2 3 5]
```

Then comparing Array1 with Array2 would return true.
and comparing Array3 with Array2 would return false.

Is there any quick and easy way of doing this. I would not know the lengths of the arrays I would be comparing. The number of elements I want to compare equals the length of the shortest vector.

Thanks!

Comment: How many of the first elements must be equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if all elements in two vectors are the same using [`isequal`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html). To check only the first n elements, you can do `Array(1:n)`, thus the entire function will be like this:

```
Array1 = [1 2 3 4]
Array2 = [1 2 3 4 5 3 2 5 7]
Array3 = [1 2 3 5]

n = 4;    % Compare the first n elements
isequal(Array1(1:n), Array2(1:n))
ans =  1

isequal(Array2(1:n), Array3(1:n))
ans = 0
```

If you use `Array1(1:n) == Array2(1:n)` you will get a piece-wise comparison resulting in `1 1 1 1`. Of course, this means you could also do:

```
all(Array1(1:n) == Array2(1:n))
ans =  1

all(Array2(1:n) == Array3(1:n))
ans =  0
```

If you want `n` to be the number of elements in the smallest vector (per your comment), as [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24752198/2338750) and [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24752205/2338750) interpret the question, you can solve it this way:

```
isequal(Array1(min([numel(Array1) numel(Array2)])), Array2(min([numel(Array1) numel(Array2)])))
```

or a bit cleaner:

```
n = min([numel(Array1) numel(Array2)])
isequal(Array1(1:n), Array2(1:n))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that will compare the initial segments of any two vectors, up to the length of the shortest vector. It returns `true` if they are identical, and `false` if they are not identical.

Note that

1. It only works correctly with vectors, not with matrices (although you could extend it to deal with matrices)
2. If any entries are `NaN` then it will always return `false`, since `NaN == NaN` is `false`.

Here it is -

```
function result = equal_initial_segment(x, y)

  N = min(length(x), length(y));

  result = isequal(x(1:N), y(1:N));

end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are just comparing the all of the elements of the shorter list to the first elements of the longer list, in which case you can just do this:

```
function same = compareLists(list1, list2)
    if length(list1) > length(list2)
         same = isequal(list2, list1(1:length(list2));
    else if
         same = isequal(list1, list2(1:length(list1));
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strmatch` for that:

```
~(isempty(strmatch(Array1, Array2)) && isempty(strmatch(Array2, Array1)))
```